# Node.js server stops responding to requests

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I have written a Node.js (14.17.1) web application using Sails.js (0.12.14) which internally uses Express.js (3.21.3). This application has been in production since more than 5 years (whith only minor version bumps to Node.js and Sails.js).

Once in a while, this server stops responding to requests. I have used logging in my controller to identify that it is not stopping anywhere in the code that I have written. I have also confirmed it by attaching a debugger.

I will give an example using a simple get API request which returns static JSON.

```
contactDetails: function (req, res) {
    return res.json({
        support: {
            email: 'help@example.com',
            phone: '0-1111-222-3333',
        },
        pricing: {
            email: 'help@example.com',
            phone: '0-1111-222-3334',
        },
    });
}
```

where `contactDetails` is bound to `get /api/v2/contact`.

In my middleware (http.js in Sails.js framework), I have modified the `res.json()` function to log a line after it is done, in this way:

```
res.originalJson = res.json
res.json = function() {
    var ret = res.originalJson(...arguments)
    console.log("res.json() done")
}
```

When I encounter this issue, I can see in the logs `res.json() done`. So I know that my function has run completely. Once I restart this Node.js instance, everything works fine, until the time this issue recurs.

I have also taken a wireguard capture of two ports, one running an instance where this issue is occurring (8091) and another where this is not happening (8092). Here is the screenshot (I have removed source and destination columns as both are 127.0.0.1):
[image: wireguard capture comparison]

Here, I can see that the whole data has already been pushed from the server to client (in 689 bytes sent in [PSH, ACK]) which the client has acknowledged. But in the instance where this issue is occurring, a final [PSH, ACK] is missing, which looks like this:
[image: wireguard capture of final PSH,ACK]
This leads me to believe that somehow the Node.js server is not closing the connection properly.

I also checked the active connections to port 8091 using `sudo netstat -anp | grep :8091`.

1. When the client (curl) is hung on the request but after `res.json()` has been called:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45558         127.0.0.1:8091          ESTABLISHED 974453/curl         
tcp6       0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN      874776/node         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8091          127.0.0.1:45558         ESTABLISHED 874776/node
```

2. After I kill the client:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45558         127.0.0.1:8091          TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN      874776/node
```

3. After about a couple of minutes:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN      874776/node
```

Can anybody tell me why this issue might be happening? Is there any limits that I need to increase? Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I would have posted the pcapng files but the API response contain actual contact information, which I don't know how to remove from the files.

Comment: Use PM2 to bring the service when it goes automatically down. Then analyse the logs in PM2 why it went down / service errors as per the Pm2 logs.

Comment: My assumption is that your node server is not properly closing connections after sending the response, leading to hanging connections and eventually filling up the available connection slots.

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury Firstly, shouldn't those hanging connections show up in netstat? Secondly, is there a limit for maximum connections?

Comment: Hanging connections should show up in netstat if they are still active. However, it's possible that the connections are in a state where they are waiting to be closed or timed out, which might not be immediately reflected in the output of netstat. For example, connections in a TIME_WAIT state, as shown in your netstat output, are connections that have been closed locally and are waiting for any delayed packets to arrive. These connections will eventually be closed and removed from the list.

Comment: Regarding maximum connections, in Linux there are system-wide limits on the maximum number of open file descriptors and maximum number of connections per IP address. You can check the maximum number of open file descriptors for your process using the `ulimit -n` command. you can also check the maximum number of connections allowed per IP address using the `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` command. (disclaimer: I have collected those commands from Internet)

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury doesn't seem like a problem with limits as I am not able to reproduce using `wrk`